# how to prove this Elasticity formula

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand this equality. How do I prove this?$$\frac{\partial\mu(x)}{\partial x_j} \cdot \frac{x_j}{\mu(x)} = \frac{\partial \log\mu(x)}{\partial \log(x_j)}$$ this assumes that $\mu(x) > 0$ and $x_j > 0$.

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  Please let us know what you've found already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the question has been well-answered, but would just like to draw your attention to the fact that there is no mystery here. let us leave aside the distraction of the partial derivative.

suppose suitable differentiability of the functions involved, and that you wish to find:
$$\frac{d (\phi \circ f)(x)}{d\phi(x)}
$$
then
$$ d(\phi \circ f)(x) = f'(x)(\phi' \circ f)(x)dx \\
d\phi(x) = \phi'(x) dx
$$
this gives, by the naive method of Leibniz and Newton
$$\frac{d (\phi \circ f)(x)}{d\phi(x)} = \frac{f'(x)(\phi' \circ f)(x)}{\phi'(x)}
$$
in the case $\phi$=$ln$ then $\phi'(x)=\frac1{x}$ and the expression simplifies to $\frac{x}{f}\frac{df}{dx}$

Comment: Furthering the discussion, when, by chain rule, you have (it's just a step for proving the same thing in this topic): (∂lnx/∂lny)=(∂lnx/∂x)(∂x/∂lny), why can I consider x as a function of lny? I found that part a bit odd, @David Holden.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{\partial\log\mu(x)}{\partial\log x_j}\cdot\frac{\partial\log x_j}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial \log \mu(x)}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial\mu(x)}{\partial x_j}\frac{1}{\mu(x)} $$

Since $\frac{\partial \log x_j}{\partial x_j}=\frac{1}{x_j}$, we obtain:
$$ \frac{\partial\log\mu(x)}{\partial\log x_j}=\frac{\partial\mu(x)}{\partial x_j}\frac{x_j}{\mu(x)} $$

Comment: I might need to refresh myself of some basic calculus now... I am not sure how we justify the first equality. Thanks!

Comment: @zsljulius An abuse of notation would suggest it's just "cancellation," but really it's the chain rule of differentiation: $$ \frac{\text df(g(x))}{\text dx}=\frac{\text df(g(x))}{\text dg(x)}\frac{\text dg(x)}{\text dx} $$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a formal definition of expressions like $\frac{df}{dg}$, but I guess it is just a shorthand to write $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$ In this case you need only to apply the “log-derivative” rule to your formula.